# How does "this" pointer happen to point to different objects?

Tags: c++, pointers, this, this-pointer

Suppose I have a class:

```
class test {
public:
   void print();
private:
   int x;
};

void test::print()  
{  
    cout<< this->x;  
}
```

and I have these variable definitions:

```
test object1;
test object2;
```

When I call `object1.print()` `this` happens to store address of `object1` and so I get `x` from `object1` printed and when I call `object2.print()` `this` happens to store address of `object2` and I get `x` from `object2` printed. How does it happen?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each non-static member function has an implicit hidden "current object" parameter that is exposed to you as `this` pointer.

So you can think that for

```
test::print();
```

there's some

```
test_print( test* this );
```

global function and so when you write

```
objectX.print();
```

in your code the compiler inserts a call to

```
test_print(&objectX);
```

and this way the member function knows the address of "the current" object.

Comment: Note: In Python, for example, this is passed implicitly but declared explicitly in the function signature (`def func(self, i)` where `self` represents an instance of the object)

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the `this` pointer being an implicit argument to the functions. Imagine a little class like

```
class C {
public:
  C( int x ) : m_x( x ) { }

  void increment( int value ) {
    m_x += value; // same as 'this->m_x += value'
  }

  int multiply( int times ) const {
    return m_x * times; // same as 'return this->m_x * times;'
  }

private:
  int m_x;
};
```

which allows you to write code like

```
C two( 2 );
two.increment( 2 );
int result = two.multiply( 3 );
```

Now, what's actually happening is that the member functions `increment` and `multiply` are called with an extra pointer argument, pointing to the object on which the function is invoked. This pointer is known as `this` inside the method. The type of the `this` pointer is different, depending on whether the method is `const` (as `multiply` is) or not (as is the case with `increment`).

You can do something like it yourself as well, consider:

```
class C {
public:
  C( int x ) : m_x( x ) { }

  void increment( C * const that, int value ) {
    that->m_x += value;
  }

  int multiply( C const * const that, int times ) const {
    return that->m_x * times;
  }

private:
  int m_x;
};
```

you could write code like

```
C two( 2 );
two.increment( &two, 2 );
int result = two.multiply( &two, 3 );
```

Notice that the type of the `this` pointer is `C const * const` for the `multiply` function, so both the pointer itself is `const` but also the object being pointed to! This is why you cannot change member variables inside a `const` method - the `this` pointer has a type which forbids it. This could be resolved using the `mutable` keyword (I don't want to get side-tracked too far, so I'll rather not explain how that works) but even using a `const_cast`:

```
int C::multiply( int times ) const {
  C * const that = const_cast<C * const>( this );
  that->m_x = 0; // evil! Can modify member variable because const'ness was casted away
  // ..
}
```

I'm mentioning this since it demonstrates that `this` isn't as special a pointer as it may seem, and this particular hack is often a better solution than making a member variable `mutable` since this hack is local to one function whereas `mutable` makes the variable mutable for *all* `const` methods of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The way to think about it is that `this` is simply a pointer to the memory for whichever object you're currently working with.  So if you do `obj1.print()`, then `this = &obj1;`.  If you do `obj2.print()`, then `this = &obj2;`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` has different values for different objects

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of class test gets it's own copy of member variable x. Since x is unique for each instance, the value can be anything you want it to be. 
The variable this, refers to the instance to which it is associated. You don't have to use the variable 'this'. You could just write:

```
void test::print()
{
   cout << x;
}
```